# SetAnchor for MapOverlay

Tags: windows-phone-8

In the map control[wp8] i have used a mapoverlay for plotting the GeoCoordinate. The issue i'm  facing is that while zoom-in and zoom-out the overlay moves out of it's location to some where else. Is there any way we can anchor it to that particular position like the "SetAnchor"  property used for anchoring the pushpin. I have tried the PostionOrigin property without getting any desired result.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Show some code, please, to better illustrate your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something similar to this,

```
        var containerCanvas = new Canvas { Height = 100, Width = 100 };
        _dragMarker = new MapOverlay();
        var dragMarkerLayer = new MapLayer();
        var image = new Image
        {
            Source = DContext != null ? new BitmapImage(new Uri(DContext.DragImagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) : new BitmapImage(),
            Height = 100,
            Width = 100,

        };


        containerCanvas.Children.Add(image);
        _dragMarker.Content = containerCanvas;
        _dragMarker.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.75);
```

It works fine for me... :)